# Published website to local IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, iis-7.5, microsoft-web-deploy

I published a asp.net mvc 4 website to IIS 7.5 (local) on windows 7 64 bit OS. It takes forever for the website to show up. I am using vs2013. After a long time it shows only the initial page, when I try to navigate to any other page, it just keeps showing the spinning wheel and nothing happens. Is there any configuration needed? I am trying the filesystem option in the publish method. I also tried webdeploy and installed webdeploy etc, but even that is the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are probably referencing a 32bit dll in your project. In general case that shouldn't be done but is better to use the default 64 bit option.

One other easy way to deploy the website is to filesystem. - just create a folder and configure the site under that folder in IIS. Its more manual, but then on production again is all about copying files from that folder to the configured production one - the usual option for standard type web hosting.

Answer (score 0):

I enabled 'Enable32bit' to true in advanced settings of the apppool and it worked like a charm. I hope this helps someone who is having the same issue.